# Facing Issue in "App Verification" in "Facebook monetization Manager"

Tags: facebook-monetization-manager, google-app-verification

in "App Verification" in "Facebook Monetization Manager" I have only one option which is "Submit for review" but in past there was another option which was "send code on email" but now there in no option of send email. can anyone guide why there is no option of  verification throufh email

Answer (score 1):

Yes Now Meta audience network changed there policy.

> You have to create App-ads.txt in the hosting. After that you will
> enter the Domain URL in Store listing on google play console and
> update.

That's it